# Power BI visualisation of active calls per time

Tags: data-structures, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'd like to create a Power BI visualisation of telephone log data. Which comes in a .csv as follows:

```
caller nr, calle nr, call start time, talk start time, call end time, duration 
2002, 2001, 09:00:01, 09:00:15, 09:02:23, 00:02:22
2003, 2004, 09:00:20, 09:00:25, 09:01:50, 00:01:30
```

The visualisation should display the amount of active calls per time. In the given example the chart should display one call from 09:00:01 to 09:02:23 but two calls from 09:00:20 till 09:01:50. However, I couldn't find any option to do so.

However I could create a chart, which shows the amount of started calls per time (minute).

Can anyone give me a hint? Many thanks in advance!

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a calendar table with minutes as grain, make the relationship, and then create measures to build visuals with that information.

Comment: Thank you. I solved the issue by coding a C++ programm, which exports a csv.